# How to plot data with domain on a circle?

Tags: plotting, data

I've got a list of data of the form `{{0,x0},...,{359,x359}}`, which represents some experimental results given in polar coordinates with fixed radius. How to plot this data on a circle , i.e. it should be something like `ListPlot` but ends should be glued together.

Comment: To reduce confusion, I recommend that you remove the underscores and write `x0` and `x359` or `x[0]` and `x[359]` instead.

Comment: [`ListPolarPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPolarPlot.html) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListPolarPlot` does what you want.

Just for fun, here is a simple alternative implementation using `Graphics` primitives, and drawing lines instead of just the points:

```
Options[circleListPlot] = {circleRadius -> .01, maxOutwardLength -> 0,
    withLines -> True};
circleListPlot[data_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{scaledData},
  If[OptionValue@maxOutwardLength == 0,
   scaledData = data,
   scaledData = {
       #[[1]],
       OptionValue@circleRadius + (#[[2]] - Min@data[[All, 2]])/(
         Max@data[[All, 2]] - Min@data[[All, 2]])
          OptionValue@maxOutwardLength
       } & /@ data
   ];
  Graphics[
   {
    Red, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, OptionValue@circleRadius],
    Darker@Green, Thin,
    Line[
       Function[pointOnUnitaryCircle,
         {
          OptionValue@circleRadius pointOnUnitaryCircle,
          #[[2]] pointOnUnitaryCircle
          }
         ]@{Cos[#[[1]] Degree], Sin[#[[1]] Degree]}
       ] & /@ scaledData
    },
   Axes -> True
   ]
  ]
```

Which you can call like this:

```
data = MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 360]];
circleListPlot[data, circleRadius -> 0.2, maxOutwardLength -> 2]
```

[image]

Or, taking from the first example in the documentation of ListPolarPlot:

```
circleListPlot[Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 360}], circleRadius -> 1]
```

[image]